# How to obtain all the URLs generated dynamically in javascript menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, url, download

I need to download all the images from the gallery of [this site](http://www.sinavimo.gov.ar/malezascontaminantes/) but I don't know how to obtain the URL of them or where these URL are stored on.

I tried to download the entire site with some programs but none of them seems to download even the menu.
Hope someone have any idea how to achieve this without having to do it manually one by one.

Here I can saw the code that produce the URLs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".text-frame").not(".default-frame").hide();
    $('#menubar .button').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("button-hover");
    });
    $('#menubar .button').click(function(){
        $(".text-frame").hide();
        $("#image-viewer").hide();
        $(".button").removeClass("button-active");
        var showTextframe = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + showTextframe).show();
        $(this).addClass("button-active");
    });

    function showImages (imgLinks){
        for (var i = 0; i < imgLinks.length; i++){
            //$("#image-box").append($('<img>').attr('src', imgLinks[i]));
            var $imgSelector = $('<a>'+ (i + 1) +'</a>')
                .data('imglink',imgLinks[i])
                .click(function(){
                    $("#image-box").find("img").attr('src', $(this).data('imglink'));
                    $("#image-links").find('a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    //alert ("I open Image" + $(this).data('imglink'));
                });
            $("#image-links").append($imgSelector);
            $("#image-links").find('a:first').trigger('click');
        }
    }

    $.get("plants_w_links.md", function(semillaMenu){
        var markdownConverter = new Showdown.converter();
        $semillaMenu = $(markdownConverter.makeHtml(semillaMenu));
        $semillaMenu.find("img").each(function(){
            var $menuimage = $(this);
            var $menulink = $(this).parent("li").find("a");
            var menuimages = $menulink.data("menuimages") || [];
            menuimages.push($menuimage.attr("src"));
            $menulink.data("menuimages",menuimages);
            $menuimage.remove();
        });

        $semillaMenu.find("a").click(function(){
            var menuImages = $(this).data("menuimages");
            //$("#image-box").empty();
            $("#image-links").empty();

            if (menuImages){
                $("#image-viewer").show();
                showImages(menuImages);

            }
        });

        $semillaMenu.addClass("sf-menu sf-vertical");
        $('#semilla-menu').html($semillaMenu);
        jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({delay:10});

    });


});
</script>
```

The function `showImages` seems to generate the URL but I don't know what to do with that.

I found here many question asking something similar but all of them talking about donwloading images with progressive URL (like `blabla.com/image1.jpg`, `blabla.com/image2.jpg`, etc.) but it is not the case, the images are generated without a pattern (or not any that I can obtain or deduce).

**EDIT:** I need to know how those functions work in order to run something similar in the Chrome inspect console that gives me all the URL instead the URL of the clicked option of the menu.

**EDIT2:** Someone in a IRC channel told me that the script may be jQuery, so I'm adding the tag.

Comment: So, you want url of all images on a web page, right?

Comment: Yes. The images I can obtain from that site are only the one that have their own URL in the <a> tag. I need the ones that the URL are generated by code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urls = new Array();      
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.images, function( img ){ urls.push( img.src ) } );
console.log( urls );
```

After execution these lines of code `urls` will contain sources of all images on the page.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, but: Where your code goes? Where I have to write your code to execute it?
EDIT: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: I wrote it on the inspect console. The Result is:
`["http://www.sinavimo.gov.ar/malezascontaminantes/img/cuadro.jpg", ""] VM1181:4
undefined`
There is something else I have to do first?

Comment: there's just probably some image tag that doesn't have the src attribute. Don't worry about `undefined`, that's the return value of the function call on second line.

Comment: I been doing some test on the answer you did. I know now what your code do and it's not what I asked for. I need the URL of all images on that site, but not the images that are at simple view, I need the ones generated by the code I posted, by the `showImage` function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally someone on the jQuery chat tell me how to solve my problem. Accesing directly to [this link](http://www.sinavimo.gov.ar/malezascontaminantes/plants_w_links.md) was the answer. The link seems to contain the structure of the menues that `semillaMenu` function format (aparently) and process to show the images on the site.

This doesn't solve my question yet, because it's only working for this case. What I wanted was a way to obtain the URLs with a script but it's solve my problem.

So I let it be unaswered if someone know how to make a script that gives all the image links without having to process manually the `plants_w_links.md` file.